# How to print enumerator alias in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have an enum that is like this:

```py
class Vehicle(Enum):
   TRUCK = 1
   CAR = 2
   FERRARI = 2
```

That is, `FERRARI` is just an alias for `CAR`. So, when i compare them like `Vehicle.CAR == Vehicle.FERRARI` it returns `True`.

However, if i print:

```py
print(Vehicle.FERRARI)
```

It returns `Vehicle.CAR`, which is expected since `FERRARI` just points to `CAR`. I'd like to know if there is any way i can overwrite this behavior while keeping the enum alias. So, when i print `FERRARI` it returns the alias and not the `CAR` enum.

Ps: i don't know if this is the most appropriate way of achieving this result. Since FERRARI can be seen as a subtype of CAR, it could also be a subclass, but i wasn't able to achieve this result with enum subclasses.

Comment: From official docs: "two enum members are allowed to have the same value. Given two members A and B with the same value (and A defined first), B is an alias to A. By-value lookup of the value of A and B will return A. By-name lookup of B will also return A"

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: I think you're facing the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how should i approach the problem properly?

Comment: Why not classify your data properly ? One `enum` for type (car, truck) another `enum` for brands ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer this enum will be used, for instance, as a property of a class. Since only cars have brands, it would be bad if this class has this property set as truck.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.  The "alias" portion of enums simply means that the aliased name (FERRARI in this case) points to the primary member (CAR in this case) -- there is no separate aliased member.